# Adding POM type dependency using m2eclipse, unable to resolve

Tags: maven, dependencies, m2eclipse, pom.xml

I am trying to add Hector dependencies to my [POM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Object_Model#Project_Object_Model). My IDE is Eclipse, and I am also using m2eclipse. Adding dependencies of JAR type is not a problem, but this dependency is of type POM. I have tried almost everything usual including cleaning, building, and using import scope but nothing seem to have helped. When I try to add `import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer;`
I get the error "The import cannot be resolved".

Is there anything else I need to do to use POM type dependencies or is there a better way of using dependencies of POM types in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the relevant class is missing in your classpath.  A search of this class indicates, it is available in [hector-core](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/me.prettyprint/hector-core/0.7.0-29/me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer.java#Serializer)

[This discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/hector-users/browse_thread/thread/c27209493c1b3fc9?pli=1) indicates how this dependency can be imported, viz. adding the following entry to your project pom (or choosing this appropriately in m2eclipse).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
    <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0-29</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe his question is not as obvious as simply including the necessary dependency.  I have experienced this problem too and am looking for a solution.  The problem can be clearer stated as the following:

Let's say I have two maven projects (project A and project B).  Project A is a simple web-app which wants to include dependencies as stated in project B.  However, project B packaging type is "pom".  This should allow all of project B's dependencies to be included into project A.  Here is an example:

Project A (packaging is "war"):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Project B (packaging is "pom")

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What we'd like to see in Eclipse is when you run maven eclipse:eclipse on Project A, that you can see the commons-lang-2.4.jar file as a dependency under project A such that you can resolve it in your code when imported.  This is not happening and I'm still looking for such a solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue if the dependency is WAR type. In this post (http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Dependency-with-war-type-td136645.html), the user has resolved the problem by adding manually the war in the classpath through eclipse an not through the `pom.xml` file.

Comment: I have filled a bug report here : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375085